# Internal error when installing scrumbler plugin to redmine

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I've installed the scrumbler plugin to Redmine for project management according to SCRUM methodology :

```
  cd plugins
 git clone git://github.com/256MbTeam/Redmine-Scrumbler.git redmine_scrumbler
 rake redmine:plugins:migrate
```

I have got in browser: `http://localhost/scrumbler/admin`

```
Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error
```

And in log file :

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Table 'redmine_production.scrumbler_project_settings' doesn't exist: SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` INNER JOIN `scrumbler_project_settings` ON `scrumbler_project_settings`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`):
  activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `query'
```

.

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/256MbTeam/Redmine-Scrumbler/blob/2b7b75a31384edba33a7d93af4d53d2feb6cbf9f/db/migrate/002_create_scrumbler_project_settings.rb#L3). Maybe somehow a condition is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

and not

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate
```